# Wcf and ExceptionDetail Issue

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, faultexception

I have created my own class like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyOperationFault : ExceptionDetail
{


    /// <summary>
    /// Contructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ex"></param>
    public MyOperationFault(Exception ex) : base(ex)
    {
    }
}
```

then my wcf service interface looks like this:

```
   [OpearationContract()]
   [FaultContract(typeof(MyOperationFault))]
   void DoWork();
```

Now everything works as expected in the dev environment - when I raise the `FaultException`:

```
   throw new FaultException<MyOperationFault>(new MyOperationFault(new Exception("Failed")));
```

It gets caught on the client's side no problem.

The problem appears when I move to test my service with `wcftestclient.exe` tool. I am getting this error:

> **Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible.
>   Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.**  
>   *Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   http://localhost:33620/MyService.svc If this is a Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please
>   check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified
>   address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the
>   MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error    URI: http://localhost:33620/MyService.svc    Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://localhost:33620/MyService.svc'.    Could not connect to
>   http://localhost:33620/MyService.svc. TCP error code 10061: No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it 127.0.0.1:33620.     Unable to connect to the remote server    No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it 127.0.0.1:33620*

As soon as I comment out the `[FaultContract(typeof(MyOperationFault))]`
 from the service's methods - the `wcftestclient` starts working without a glitch. How to tackle this?

Comment: do you really want your exception class to be derived from ExceptionDetail. I tried your code, and even I was not able to add it to wcftestclient.exe. The reason being the parameter constructor

Comment: Are you able to access WSDL? What happens if you add parameterless constructor?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Turns out the classes used as detail parameter need a parameterless constructor in order to work...

The TestClient probably failed because MyOperationFault was lacking a parameterless constructor.

The solution i came up with was adding a private parameterless constructor as in

```
[DataContract]
public class MyOperationFault : ExceptionDetail
{
    /// i dont know why but this fixed the issue
    private MyOperationFault()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ex"></param>
    public MyOperationFault(Exception ex) : base(ex)
    {
    }
}
```